# ¿Tiene nombre el punto sobre la letra i?

Tags: escritura, alfabeto, diacríticos

En [esta respuesta de 2015](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/13383/11102) hay un intercambio de comentarios entre Guifa y dokeryZ sobre las palabras en inglés *tilde* y *[tittle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tittle)*

Entiendo que *tilde* en inglés es solo para la marca ( ~ ) que va en español sobre la **n** o en portugués como en *São Paulo*, pero en español tilde es el símbolo 
( ´ ) que se usa para representar el *acento gráfico u ortográfico*.

Guifa nos ilustra en su respuesta con el dato de que en inglés el punto sobre la i tiene por nombre **[tittle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tittle)** por lo que me pregunto ¿tiene nombre el punto sobre la i en español?.

Comment: Nunca había oído *tittle*.  Donde yo, se dice *dot*.

Comment: Apart from the biblical phrase _jot and title_ I have never heard this used in South East England. We use dot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pues aunque parezca mentira, se llama...

> [**punto**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UgMIq14)
>
> 2. m. Rasgo gráfico sobrescrito en la i y la j minúsculas, y que forma parte de estas letras.

Tampoco yo lo sabía y me encontré la clave en una [discusión de WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/el-punto-de-la-i.122499/#post-796402) en que mencionaban la entrada *39. m. Ortogr. Nota ortográfica que se pone sobre la i y la j*. Y de hecho el [mapa de diccionarios](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/mapa-de-diccionarios) muestra que estaba efectivamente en esa 39.ª posición en la edición de 2001. Ignoro el motivo para tal reordenación.

Comment: :-) Excelente. Había buscado pero nunca llegué a la referencia más obvia.

Comment: ...O *puntito*.

Comment: ¡No quepo en mí de asombro! ¿Es que nunca habéis oído la expresión "**poner los puntos sobre las íes**"?

Comment: @Jdamian en inglés existe la expresión **dot the i and cross the t** pero aún así el "dot" no se llama dot sino _tittle_ así que no necesariamente una cosa implica la otra.

Answer (score 2):

[ápice](https://dle.rae.es/?id=3A93Xnp) es el nombre correcto del punto sobre letras

> 4. m. desus. Acento o cualquier otro de los signos ortográficos que se ponen sobre las letras.

Comment: Bienvenido a [Spanish.se] Jorge. Coincido con el comentario que te han hecho y me he permitido hacer un edit (añadiendo un enlace a la web del DRAE) para ayudarte a entender cómo mejorar mediante el formato y enlaces el contenido de la respuesta para que sea más fácil de entender y muestre en la propia contribución la explicación que estás intentando dar. Espero que esto te sirva de ayuda para tus próximas contribuciones (que espero sean muchas).